# (jQuery) Scroll event.. I want to scroll the document to the point specified if the user scroll the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to implement a scroll function.. So the default of scroll is disabled. And if the user use the scroll button, I want it to be set to the point I want.. How can I implement this function? window.scrollTop is not working.. I tried a lot of different methods but all were not working..

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $(body).scrollTop = 3000px;
})
```

Comment: Just remove the px and your should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `scrollTop` property only accepts an integer (not pixels). Omit the `px` and it should be fine.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('body').get(0).scrollTop = 3000; // note that this does only work if body has overflow
    // if it hasn't, use window instead
});
```

Comment: I don't understand.. The $('body') already selected the BODY why do I still need to use get(0) in order for that to work?

Also. Is there a way to know if the user scrolled north / south?

Comment: $('body') returns a jQuery object; get(0) gives you access to the corresponding node (within the DOM) - this enables you to access DOM properties like 'scrollTop'

Answer (score 3):

There is a plugin for JQuery called ScrollTo that might do exactly what you need.

Check it out here:  http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

Comment: Yes, I tried to read the code but I didn't understand any of it.. I'm still new to this programming thing